# Find location of Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio

I am following this tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application
How do I find the location of the circled database on the hard disk? I need to know what directory it is in.
Thanks[image: Screenshot]

Comment: right click, Properties -> Files

Comment: It's probably hosted by the SQL Server engine. Why do you need the file anyways?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the `Database location` is a flawed concept:

Sure, the database might be hosted on your computer on an SQL Server, but it could also be hosted on another server, to which you don't have file system access, and you should not be able to find any (significant) information about anything outside the SQL Server Instance.

Another example could be (but VERY improbable) that the Database is not located on ANY hard drive. It could be totally located in memory, without any data on the disk. I'm unaware of such MSSQL compatible servers, but [the concept exists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-memory_database).

Answer (score 0):

Go to properties of selected database and check connection string.

Dont forgot to mark it as answer and vote for it if it had helped you :)